# Webhook Error: No signatures found matching (only on Vercel)

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, webhooks, vercel

I'm trying to integrate Stripe to my simple e-commerce web app.
I'm using Next.js and Vercel for deployment but I'm struggling with this problem:
only when my web app is deployed the webhook I created in order to handle Stripe payment events return this error:

> Webhook Error 1: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing

I don't know why hen I try it on localhost (using Stripe Cli whit the command `stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost/api/webhooks`) it works!

This is my webhook code:

```
import { buffer } from 'micro';
import Cors from 'micro-cors';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY!, {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
});

const webhookSecret: string = process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!;

// Stripe requires the raw body to construct the event, so we have to diable the next parser
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

const cors = Cors({
  allowMethods: ['POST', 'HEAD'],
});

const webhookHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const buf = await buffer(req);
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']!;

    let event: Stripe.Event;

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(buf.toString(), sig, webhookSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      // On error, log and return the error message.
      res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error 1: ${err.message} \n Request: ${req} \n Result: ${res} \n Signature: ${sig}`);
      return;
    }
    // DO STUFF ....
}
```

The signature returned on Vercel is something like this: `t=1628151795,v1=44ba901938e34c6247a22f5a7990aeae8738a75cd4091b57723a8da7fcde031e,v0=4698d4bb0b9f66f970788e312c84ed78d7f9531000815e44bdce0a6fd0f4f786`.

Thanks for all in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct webhook secret when deploying to Vercel? Each webhook has a different key (as noted [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures)), including between live and test mode.

Comment: @JonathanSteele I'm an idiot. I was giving to Vercel a Restricted Key instead the specific Webhook key. Thanks for the answer.